# Show exit popup to non logged in users

Tags: magento-1.9

We are using the following extension: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/exit-intent-popup-2.html

Where should the following code be placed to only show the popup when users are not logged in:

```
if(!(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add Customer Login condition in below file with or inside `isActivePopup()` condition.

> app\design\frontend\base\default\template\mt\exitpopup\popup.phtml